# Struggling with geo data/polygons in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial

I have a table which contains an field `zoneShape` of the type `Polygon`.

When inserting some geometry in this field, in phpmyadmin it says: affected 1 row. The row is added, but the geometry field says it's size is 0B.

This is the Insertion code:

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON(50.866753 5.686455, 50.859819 5.708942, 50.851475 5.722675, 50.841611 5.720615, 50.834023 5.708427, 50.840744 5.689373, 50.858735 5.673923, 50.866753 5.686455)';
INSERT INTO zone SET zoneShape = PolygonFromText(@g)
```

As you can see; the first and last point are the same, so the polygon is closed.

Can anyone help me with adding this polygon to the database?
Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you need to add some extra brackets around the Points; because the standard uses an outside and inside line aka holes or islands.

So:

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((50.866753 5.686455, 50.859819 5.708942, 50.851475 5.722675, 50.841611 5.720615, 50.834023 5.708427, 50.840744 5.689373, 50.858735 5.673923, 50.866753 5.686455))';
                  ^                                                                                              outside                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO zone SET zoneShape = PolygonFromText(@g)` doesn't look like a valid INSERT statement to me. Did you mean `INSERT INTO zone (zoneShape) VALUES (PolygonFromText(@g));`?

Comment: It is a valid insert Statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html second example